# Longest “Short” Simple Path

Tags: graph

The input is a directed, weighted graph with two nodes and the longest possible length of a “short” path, L.
You are required to find the longest simple path between the two given nodes with length not greater than L (i.e. the longest “short” simple path between the two nodes).
I do not know how to modify Dijkstra’s to check for simple paths. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Hey there - can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Tried to use complete search with bitmask (for the simple path) to get the answer, but it is really slow. I'm not sure whether Dijkstra can be used for this problem (or Bellman Ford/Floyd Warshall, for that matter).